# Why Method call inside onSubmit throws error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I try to call metetor method but it is throwing me error "Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.call is not a function" but when I try to call same in another file inside imports/api/some.js this works, meaning the call code is correct but it is working inside onSubmit why ? Here is github [url](https://github.com/mgonekar/Meteor-Test-App)

**File : imports/ui/otp.js**

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let otp = this.refs.otp.value.trim();

  Meteor.call('find-otp', otp, (error, result) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log('otp error check', error);
    } else {
      console.log('otp res check', result);
    }
   });
}
```

**File : imports/api/db.js**

```
   Meteor.methods({
    'find-otp' (otp) {
        // if(!this.userId) {
        //     throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
        //  }
         console.log('otpcheck', otp);
         return true;
        //  return otp; // also I try this
    }
});
```

Comment: are you importing `Meteor`? i.e: `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'`

Comment: thanx, my silly mistake I forget to use {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you properly import Meteor:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
```